# How can I access an object added in a dictionary in a Django view

Tags: python, django

I have added the dictionary to the object with this:

```
dict['var1'] = {'value': 'tetsing'}
```

`object.dict = dict`

Now I am confused how to access the dictionary in view. Do I use:

`object.dict['var1']['value']`  or `object.dict.var1.value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should to rename variable and attribute names so that they aren't in conflict with built-in names like `dict`.

Now, in normal Python code, use the first way.

**However**, if you are trying to access it from the Django template, use the second one.

Comment: But will the second portion work in viewys.py or not. becaus ei have used in some code and it worked. i was confused which is right way

Comment: @user1758043 a good way to find out is by trying. So try typing it up in Python interactive shell and see if which way works. Hint: the second way should not work in your views.py unless you have overwritten `__getattr__` and `__setattr__` of `dict`